# Simple Surface integral of a cylinder without a z parameter

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, surface-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

[Raw Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHeG4.png)

Basically trying to calculate the surface integral of the top surface described by the equation:
$x^2 + y^2 = 9$ as the outside cylinder with the top defined by $x + z = 5$ - a nice and simple integral $\int yzds$. My understanding for the top surface is to take x and y as parameters, (meaning z = 5 - x), which you can then use to get the integral $\int xz \sqrt{2} dxdy$ Which can then be converted into polar co-ordinates to solve. This is where my problem comes in - there's a z? With drd$\theta$, I can't convert the z. If you convert that into x-5, the resulting integral is a mess and I can't solve it. I've attached my working so far beneath:

Any ideas where I went wrong or which direction I should go?

Thanks in advance!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k92QR.png

Comment: You have to solve only the integral over cylinder surface (in your picture $S_2$, the orange surface)

Comment: I understand that you can ignore the bottom surface (as z = 0 for all values), but you can't ignore the top surface can you? y doesn't always equal zero, even though the surface does rest on that plane.

Comment: I ignore the bottom and the top surfaces because the problem is "where $S$ is the part of the half cylinder", that is, your integral is over the cylinder, just a piece. Planes only are used to limit this piece. Subsequently, they are involved in the projection to solve the double integral. You undertand me?